# The continuity of multivariable function based on outside parameter r

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

I stumbled upon this question:

**For what values of the number $r$ is the function**

$
f(x,y,z) = 
\begin{cases} 
\frac{(x + y + z)^r}{x^2+y^2+z^2}, & (x,y) \neq (0,0,0) \\
 0, & (x,y,z) = (0,0,0) \\
\end{cases}
$

**continuous on $R^3$?**

I tried to divide it by cases: $r<0, r=0, 1>r>0, r>=1$ but I am really bothered by the r being a power to $x+y+z$.

If $r>=1$, the problem is that once $x+y+z<0$, some $r$ with odd numerator over an even denominator like $\frac{5}{2}$ can make the function not continuous since somewhere down the line I would see a root of a negative number.

Is there another way I could tackle this problem?
Someone recommended me to sticking to integer values of $r$. Will that be alright?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [spherical coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html)
$$x=t\cos \theta\sin \phi,y=t\sin \theta\sin \phi,z=t\cos \phi$$
You're looking at
$$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{t^r(\cos\theta\sin\phi+\sin\theta\sin\phi+\cos \phi)^r}{t^2}=\lim_{t\to 0}t^{r-2}(\cos\theta\sin\phi+\sin\theta\sin\phi+\cos \phi)^r$$
Now the limit must be $0$ for every $\theta,\phi$ discuss the cases when $r<2$,$r=2$ and $r>2$ when is the limit $0$?

Comment: hmm... I didn't know that you could extend parametric $r sinθ$ and $r cosθ$ into 3 variable functions. I know that I could do with $r > 2$ now but I need to look out for $r=2$ in case.

Comment: @DFrank For $r=2$ should be easy enough,try picking a random angle for $\theta,\phi$ you will end up with something $\neq 0$

Comment: oh yeah. I was alarmed that I'd get a $0^0$ but that's not the case here, I could simplify that in limits.